# Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'never' when using ReturnType<typeof myFunction>

Tags: typescript

Hi all can someone help me with this please:

```
function guard <Data>({ handler }: { handler: (data: Data) => Promise<{ statusCode: number }> }) {
  return async (data: Data) => {
    const response = await handler(data);
    return response;
  };
}

const ping = guard<never>({
  handler: async () => {
    return { statusCode: 200 };
  }
});

export const events: Record<
  string,
  ReturnType<typeof guard>
> = {
  ping
};
```

on the part where I add `ping` to `events`, it will say:

```
Type '(data: never) => Promise<{ statusCode: number; }>' is not assignable to type '(data: unknown) => Promise<{ statusCode: number; }>'.
  Types of parameters 'data' and 'data' are incompatible.
    Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'never'.
```

While I could use `any`, I want to be specific with my typings and be able to use `never` whenever I won't actually use the parameter.

Here's an example code for the problem

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcxAQwE4BMA8ARNKNAPgAoBvRACzTCwBsBTDRAXwC5FKa6mNPSWQmk4EiASkQBeYogAKGOAFsYAZ0Y5KqolBCqAwnCyNOYEEoBGzNrNaTyAWABQiRBka6MSNKoCekREFhUWFJGS5nV1cIBG03RlUAB1jGaUQ0AHc0GChqWgZmIIkAbkio908kdySU0pc2OtZnZxiwOMSYMGQ01ExcMEYAN2YyR3qeAv50vwCitDDZMajEVtU4JgA6ejhkOfE65YqQLy5EbUI9Q2NOACYABjuGsqanOzqW2Nzkrp70bE1EFAElBONoMJ1uqxRmUJnxOD5-BBAkIJNJFmVorF1owtjs9gdyh5jkgtDpLkYTIh7o9WASXm9mk5GAAPZIYXKrXJDRhgKCqTgAJUYMX+YIhABpEELKgAVXyJDRQeWMODAFB-LDEWRSCL1DpdcVlb7IZy05xAA)

Comment: I don't see any use in the `events` object. When you try to use it, you're gonna have to narrow down the type of the function anyways.

Comment: So just leave the types on events object as `any` or something else? The point there is that it prevents you from adding a value in `events` object that doesn't conform to its type.

Answer (score 0):

Let the inference do its job,

`ping` is not `(data: never) => Promise<{ statusCode: number;}>` but `(data: unknown) => Promise<{ statusCode: number;}>`

```
function guard<Data>({ handler }: { handler: (data: Data) => Promise<{ statusCode: number }> }) {
  return async (data: Data) => {
    const response = await handler(data);
    return response;
  };
}

const ping = guard({ // could also be guard<unknown>(...)
  handler: async (data) => {
    console.log(data);
    return { statusCode: 200 };
  }
});

export const events: Record<string, ReturnType<typeof guard>> = {
  ping // ok 
};
```

The other possibility being, setting the guard generic type to any : `export const events: Record<string, ReturnType<typeof guard<any>>>`

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcxAQwE4BMA8ARNKNAPgAoBvRACzTCwBsBTDRAXwC5FKa6mNPSWQmk4EiASkQBeYogAKGOAFsYAZ0Y5KqolBCqAwnCyNOYEEoBGzNrNaTyAWABQiRBka6MSNKoCekREFhUWFJGS5nV1cIBG03RlUAB1jGaUQ0AHc0GChqWgZmIIkAbkio908kdySU0pc2OtZnZxiwOMSYMGQ01ExcSigEqE5tDE7u1jJKAHppxCZcqCpUmKUOvjzeVKXUzuBmRkhGMp4C-nS-AKK0MNlHeujYuCYAOno4ZGvxOqj4yq5ENpCHpDMZOAAmAAMkIaZSaTjsdWcjAAHskMLlWnFGAA3Q5QVScABKjBi2Bwo3GABpECTKgAVXyJDRQJmMODAFDocm0XzEflpSiIWaIOAsdSLZYoQ7MGAQRBQODpMC+ModLrOVh1IA)

Comment: yes that will work for this very specific code, however, have you considered other types? i.e. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcxAQwE4BMA8ARNKNAPgAoBvRACzTCwBsBTDRAXwC5FKa6mNPSWQmk4EiASkQBeYogAKGOAFsYAZ0Y5KqolBCqAwnCyNOYEEoBGzNrNaTyAWABQiRBka6MSNKoCekREFhUWFJGS5nV1cIBG03RlUAB1jGaUQ0AHc0GChqWgZmIIkAbkio908kdySU0pc2OtZnZxiwOMSYMGQ01ExcSigEqE5tDE7u1jJHep4C-nS-AKK0MNlpqMRW1TgmADp6OGRl8TqNipAvLkRtQj1DY04AJgAGZ4aypqc7OudGAA9khhcltcowAG6MMBQVScABKjBi2Bwo3GABpEPDKgAVXyJDRQXGMODAFDobDEWRSCL1DpdZysOpAA

Comment: @aprilmintacpineda Then see my edit and specify that the guard parameter could be anything.

Comment: @aprilmintacpineda either way I would let the compiler handle the inference by removing the type when using `guard(...)`

Comment: I think I failed to specify the core of the problem, I want to be specific in the typings and be able to use `never`

Comment: @aprilmintacpineda Then make it a union : `export const events: Record<string, ReturnType<typeof guard> | ReturnType<typeof guard<never>>> = {
  ping,
  pong
};`

Comment: That one actually works, but someone might have better solution, because I kinda find that dirty.

Comment: Since you can't have `never` in `ReturnType<typeof guard>` that will be the only solution.

Answer (score -1):

The type system in typescript is built upon the formal definition of type theory, so if you want to understand **why** you're getting this error, you need to understand the basics of type theory.

I recommend reading this article: https://blog.logrocket.com/when-to-use-never-and-unknown-in-typescript-5e4d6c5799ad/

From the above mentioned article:

> `unknown` is the set of all possible values. Any value can be assigned to a variable of type `unknown`. `never` is the empty set. There is no value that can be assigned to variable of type `never`. In fact, it is an error for the type of value to resolve to `never` because that would be a contradiction.

Comment: I'm not really new to typescript, though I don't claim to be an expert or even a senior in it, I do understand the basics of typings and I originally came from typed languages -- C#, C, C++, and Java before I met JavaScript. I'm sorry, but this answer doesn't really help with the problem above.